# How to check for a particular value in a column and delete the entire row corresponding to its value?

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have a set of 100 part numbers in a particular sheet and want to eliminate the data corresponding to those 100 part numbers from my Master Part List sheet (which contains a huge list of parts). I don't know how to proceed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Filter will do this for you fairly easily.  If you have a sheet with the part numbers listed, you can use that as the criteria range.  Once filtered, simply delete the visible rows and remove the filter.

Advanced Filter setup

[image: advanced filter]

Delete visible rows

[image: delete rows]

Once deleted, you can clear the filter to get back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

You can run a LOOP to go through and delete the rows with the corresponding parts.  I'm practicing VBA, but this should be exactly what you want.

```
Edited out incorrect code.
```

Comment: Incrementing `i` after deleting will lead to values potentially being missed since the new current row becomes `i` and not `i+1`.  Aside from that, this approach does not work well for 100 part numbers since it relies on the number being hard-coded in VBA.  If you want to do it this way, you should really check if the current `PART` is in the list of 100 using `Application.Match` and the appropriate ranges.  Also, there is no need to do `Selection` stuff here... `PART.EntireRow.Delete` works just fine.

Comment: I appreciate the help even if I'm terribly wrong.  I've been reading up as much as possible and learning slowly.

Wouldn't using application match require using a new sheet with a list of parts you want to remove?  Wouldn't it be terrible to hardcode the ranges using the long parts list, especially if the list changes.

Comment: The premise of the question was that there were already 2 sheets.  One has the master list and the other is a list to check against the master.  I agree that hard-coding is a bad idea... your original code had the parts hard-coded as `PARTNUMBER` and `PARTNUMBER2`.